# Delete list command deletes all elements from the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a series of commands to make a list: !addlist, !viewlist, and !deletelist.

For the list I am using a JSON file:

```json
{
  "listContent": []
}
```

And for the command file for the !deletelist command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const list = require('../list.json')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    name: 'deletelist',
    execute(message, args) {
        var rawContent = fs.readFileSync('list.json')
        var content = JSON.parse(rawContent)
        var contentList = content.listContent
        var deletedOne = contentList[parseInt(args[0])]

        content.listContent.splice(deletedOne)

        message.channel.send(`${deletedOne} has been deleted!`)

        fs.writeFile('list.json', JSON.stringify(content), function writeJSON(err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is that instead of deleting the specified element in the array, it deletes all of them. I don't get an error or anything, my list just becomes empty.

Comment: For starters, `splice` takes an index value, right now you're passing an object. Use `parseInt(args[0])` instead in splice, which then returns the deleted value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @lux I did that, and now instead of deleting all of them, it deletes everything after the one i specify. Eg. array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

if i try and delete "b", it will also delete c and d, leaving me with just a

Comment: If you have not specified a `deleteCount` (the second argument to `splice`) then all the elements right of `start` (the first argument to `splice`) will be deleted. Try `content.listContent.splice(parseInt(args[0]), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I need to:

1. Change the `.splice(deletedOne)` to `.splice(parseInt(args[0]))` (Thanks Lux)
2. Add a number of elements to replace, so I needed it to be `.splice(parseInt(args[0]), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think `Array.filter` is a bit cleaner than `Array.splice`. Also, make sure you're checking if the argument is valid:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'deletelist',

  execute(message, args) {
    const rawContent = fs.readFileSync('list.json');
    const content = JSON.parse(rawContent);
    const indexToRemove = parseInt(args[0], 10);

    if (!indexToRemove) {
      return message.channel.send(`Not removed, "${args[0]}" is an invalid argument.`);
    }
    
    const deletedOne = content.listContent[indexToRemove];

    content.listContent = content.listContent.filter(
      (_, index) => index !== indexToRemove,
    );

    message.channel.send(`${deletedOne} has been deleted!`);

    fs.writeFile('list.json', JSON.stringify(content), (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
  },
};
```